# Update code igniter config file during installation

Tags: php, codeigniter, configuration, installation

I know this question asked multiple times but almost all answer telling `save in db` or `$this->config->set_item`.

However those answers do not apply for me. I'm not making a website but an open source project and working on the installation script for non technical persons, that will setup every thing for user during installation. For this I need to update config file with user specific settings during installation and form admin panel later, if user need.

Obviously saving in DB doesn't applicable as I even need to write DB credentials in config file through installation script. `$this->config->set_item` is also not applicable as it set only for current session and I want to set it permanently.

Right now I'm working on idea of creating config file templates and update variables there. Is it right way to achieve requirements? Again another problem here, if user change some setting from admin panel (say database credentials), changes will not be reflected immediately. Is there any workaround or better solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just read config files as common files like *.txt, then parse and change what you need. For example, you want to change username for connection to database (I don't check this code, it's just an example):

```
$out = '';
$pattern = '$db[\'default\'][\'username\']';
$newValue = 'root';
$fileName = "application/config/database.php";
if(file_exists($fileName)) {
    $file = fopen($fileName,'r+');
    while(!feof($file)) { 
        $line = fgets($file);
        if(strpos($line, $pattern) !== false){
            $out = $pattern . " = '". $newValue . "'";
        }else{
            $out = $line;
        }
    }
    file_put_contents($file, $out);
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ToxaBes. This will solve issue during installation as installation script will be a simple PHP file and wont depend on CI. However can you suggest any idea about second part? How can I change config values from admin panel, which is basically a CI controller? If I apply same logic, new values will not be reflected in CI immediately?

Comment: Yes, it you want to change it from admin panel, you can use the same logic. For applying changes immediately you can set up ENVIRONMENT option in index.php to "development" (~line 21). This mean what no cache will be used. If you use another cache mechanism, you can clean cache after changing config with somrthing like this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html

Comment: And please note, if you use PDO for DB connection and change database config file, you should close and open new PDO connection.